# OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001C4EA23AE08>

Tags: python, scrapy-pipeline

When I use scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline to downlload images, I am getting an error;

the error code return is

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\files.py", line 401, in media_downloaded
    checksum = self.file_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 101, in file_downloaded
    return self.image_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 105, in image_downloaded
    for path, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 118, in get_images
    orig_image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.body))
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2590, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000014A3DC90728>
```

what does this mean??

Comment: That does not look like the full traceback.

Comment: It is the full traceback now.

Comment: It looks like scapy is trying to load images in the page into PIL. But at least one of them is not in a format PIL knows. What you have to do exactly to work around it totally depends on your code. *(Which you did not provide.)*